# Django reverse url to onetoonefield on success

Tags: python, django, url, one-to-one

Good day SO!

Recently I've started working on Django, got myself a situation which I can't find the right solution on the web to solve it. So I've got a little question about URL reversing on a success. Currently when an user successfully creates an account, the user gets reversed to a profile based on the user_id which just got created:

```
class Create(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm  # inherits from django's UserCreationForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:profile', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

This is working properly. Now I created a profile module with a OneToOneField
to the django.auth.models User model. When creating a new account, a signal is send to the create_profile_on_registration method.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile_on_registration(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    ...
```

This is also working properly, a new profile is created on user account registration. Now I would like to reverse the user to the new created profile_id instead of the user_id. However, I cant figure out exactly how to get this properly to work. Can you give me a little push in the right direction on how to approach this issue? I can't match up the right google search words or find any examples which explains or shows how to achieve this properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `self.object.profile_id` or `self.object.profile.id`?

Comment: self.object.profile.id worked like a sunshine. Django creates great relations, works even simpler then I've thought. Thanks mate!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I remember now, `self.object.profile_id` won't work, because it's the reverse relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a [one to one field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) to your user model,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

you can access the user from the profile

```
profile.user
```

and you can also access the `profile` from the user

```
user.profile
```

In your view, `self.object` is the user, so `self.object.profile.id` will give you the profile id.